# Return a value based on ID and date in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a difficult time trying to produce the following result in cell C2-C4.

There are 2 sheets: "Status Check" (1)
[image]

and "Status History" (2)

[image]

Goal: to return result (in sheet (1) Column C) that reflects the status of a particular ID based on the date in column A. Information about ID is listed in sheet (2) with 'effective date' and 'status' and associated ID.

My solution has been to use filter function to list all the possible dates and the associated status in column D-K.
D2 = TRANSPOSE(SORT(FILTER('Status History'!$B:$B,'Status History'!$A:$A=$B2),,1,))
H2 = TRANSPOSE(FILTER('Status History'!$C:$C,'Status History'!$A:$A=$B2))

Like this:[image]
From there, I used ifs formulas to produce the appropriate status based on the date in Column A
The desired results are in C2-C4 with C2 = IF(OR(AND(A2>=D2,ISBLANK(E2)),(AND(A2>=D2,A2<E2))),H2,IF(OR(AND(A2>=E2,ISBLANK(F2)),AND(A2>=E2,A2<F2)),I2,IF(OR(AND(A2>=F2,ISBLANK(G2)),AND(A2>=F2,A2<G2)),J2,IF(A2>=G2,K2))))

This is seems to be resource intensive when file is big. So I am looking to see if there is a solution to produce similar result using a simpler formula in column C only - not needing to list the info in D-K.

Thank you for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, you also can use Filter feature to solve this problem. 1. Select the column range you want to look up value, and click Data > Filter. See screenshot: 2. Then click the arrow button in the first cell of you selected range, and check the value you want to look up only in the drop-down list.

Comment: Manish, thank you. I am familiar with the function you are talking about. This is not what I am looking for. Cell D2 formula is =TRANSPOSE(SORT(FILTER('Status History'!$B:$B,'Status History'!$A:$A=$B2),,1,)) , cell H2 = =TRANSPOSE(FILTER('Status History'!$C:$C,'Status History'!$A:$A=$B2)). and C2 = =IF(OR(AND(A2>=D2,ISBLANK(E2)),(AND(A2>=D2,A2<E2))),I2,IF(OR(AND(A2>=E2,ISBLANK(F2)),AND(A2>=E2,A2<F2)),J2,IF(OR(AND(A2>=F2,ISBLANK(G2)),AND(A2>=F2,A2<G2)),K2,IF(A2>=G2,L2)))) to arrive at my solution. I cannot seem to able to arrive at the results for C2, C3, C4 without using these formulas.

Comment: Please format the answer and include the screenshot promised in your answer.